# How to populate ListView from an Array?

Tags: android, arraylist, android-listview

I am very new into android. I need to populate a ListView. As it is right now I am just adding into an array and then trying to populate the view. It will unltimately be done from an existing database.

The list does not display in the listView widget.

The `Main.xml` is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="#0000CC"
        android:background="#E8E8F0"
        android:text="@string/textview1"
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:autoText="false"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#3399FF"
        android:layout_height="461dp"
        android:id="@+id/metroList"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

My `myActivity` file:

```
package com.bkane56.metrolink;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    Button button;
    TextView textView;
    ListView listView;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
//        button.setOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener(this));
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.metroList);
    }
}
```

and my file for filling using an `arrayAdapter`:

```
package com.bkane56.metrolink;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MetroStopList extends ListActivity {


    public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ListView metroList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.metroList);

        ArrayList<String> metroStop = new ArrayList<String>();
            metroStop.add("LAMBERT MAIN TRML METROLINK STATION");
            metroStop.add("LAMBERT EAST TRML METROLINK STATION");
            metroStop.add("RICHMOND HEIGHTS METROLINK STATION");
            metroStop.add("CLAYTON METROLINK STATION");
            metroStop.add("BRENTWOOD METROLINK STATION");
            metroStop.add("MAPLEWOOD METROLINK STATION");
            metroStop.add("SUNNEN METROLINK STATION");
            metroStop.add("FORSYTH METROLINK STATION");
            metroStop.add("SHREWSBURY METROLINK STATION");
            metroStop.add("NORTH HANLEY METROLINK STATION");
            metroStop.add("UMSL NORTH METROLINK STATION"); 

//more of the same...the list is a total of 36


    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, metroStop);

    metroList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated. I am sure I will have more questions when I get further along.

Comment: Please explain what you see when you run your app and how it differs from what you want. Also, please show your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this answer will help you. If you think that I do not understand your question, let me know and I will add more.

Basically, I am not sure why are you using two .java classes. You can use just one in order to populate your ListView. Also, using ListActivity is good for this purpose, but you need to be aware of some things when using it. [Here](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/app/listactivity/android-listactivity-example/) you can find good example with explanations on how to use ListActivity.

This is my implementation of your code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private List<String> metroStop;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        metroStop = new ArrayList<String>();
        metroStop.add("LAMBERT MAIN TRML METROLINK STATION");
        metroStop.add("LAMBERT EAST TRML METROLINK STATION");
        metroStop.add("RICHMOND HEIGHTS METROLINK STATION");
        metroStop.add("CLAYTON METROLINK STATION");
        metroStop.add("BRENTWOOD METROLINK STATION");
        metroStop.add("MAPLEWOOD METROLINK STATION");
        metroStop.add("SUNNEN METROLINK STATION");
        metroStop.add("FORSYTH METROLINK STATION");
        metroStop.add("SHREWSBURY METROLINK STATION");
        metroStop.add("NORTH HANLEY METROLINK STATION");
        metroStop.add("UMSL NORTH METROLINK STATION");

        ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row_layout, R.id.listText, metroStop);
        setListAdapter(myAdapter);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mainText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="My list" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mainText"
        android:background="#aaaaaa" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**row_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example.populatefromarray" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```